# Docker Container Start Command Did Not Get .bashrc variables

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker to execute a command when starting the container but seems the environment variable did not get from the .bashrc file, please give me some advice.
thanks

dockerFile I add this to .bashrc:
 `echo "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/models/research:/models/research/slim" >> /root/.bashrc`

docker-compose.yml file with:

`command: ["python2", "/usr/bin/supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]`

PS:if I exec echo $PYTHPATH or just exec python2 /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf from container, there have not issues.

The System is Ubuntu 16.04

supervisor config:

```
[program:mosquitto-subscrible]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=python3 detection.py start_mosquitto_subscrible 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
directory=/var/www/html/detection
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/detection/logs/detection.log
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  tensorflow:
    container_name: object-detection
    build:
    context: ./tensorflow
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # environment:
    #   - PYTHONPATH=:/models/research:/models/research/slim
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html:cached
      - ./tensorflow/supervisor:/etc/supervisor/conf.d
    command: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null']
    # command: ["python2", "-c", "/usr/bin/supervisord", "--nodaemon","--configuration", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

In conclusion, I write a command in Dockfile `echo "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/models/research:/models/research/slim" >> /root/.bashrc` to make /models/research can be found by PYTHON.

there have a python model `/models/research/object_detection`.

with my supervisor, the command `python3 detection.py start_mosquitto_subscrible` can't find object_detection model if I start `supervisord` just from docker-compose command instead of exec it inside docker container.

**supervisord need python2 to start, my code needs python3**

Comment: Not sure what the base image here is, but `.bashrc` probably has a check for interactive usage at the top (something like `case $- in ..` or `[ -z $PS1 ]` or similar.

Comment: @muru, the system is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yep, there should be something like `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` at the top of root's `.bashrc`.

Comment: @muru, this command is already been there.

Comment: That reference to `$PYTHONPATH` will be expanded at the time /root/.bashrc is *created,* not when it's run. Is that what you want?

Comment: @l0b0, I want that path exists when running the command from docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/.bashrc wont run untill the shell is opened interactively, that's why no issues when you do `docker exec` which is interactive, see the first few lines of bashrc file :

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

you need to comment these lines.

If you just need one Environment variable, better get the value of PYTHON_PATH from your container and add the complete variable to your docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 2):

```
command: ["python2", "/usr/bin/supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

The command you've provided is using the exec syntax. See the [documentation on `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) (the same applies to `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT`):

> If you use the shell form of the `CMD`, then the `<command>` will execute
>   in `/bin/sh -c`:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -
> ```
>
> If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must
>   express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the
>   executable. This array form is the preferred format of `CMD`. Any
>   additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the
>   array:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> CMD ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]
> ```

In your case, you want a bash shell to process the `.bashrc` file, which means you need something along the lines of:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "python2 /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

---

Edit: with the /root/.bashrc in ubuntu:16.04, you'll see the following at the top of the file:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

You can modify the file before this line with this sed command:

```
sed -i '4s;^;export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/models/research:/models/research/slim\n;' /root/.bashrc
```

---

I'd consider placing this in a script used to start the container instead of hacking the .bashrc, e.g. a start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/models/research:/models/research/slim
exec python2 /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

And then add that to your image with:

```
COPY start.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /start.sh # if your build server doesn't have this permission set
CMD [ "/start.sh" ]
```

Comment: Hi @BMitch, I did what you said , but still got the error from my python code. "ImportError: No module named 'object_detection'"

Comment: Hi @BMitch,  I edited my question again, hope it is much clear for you.

Comment: Review the above link again please. The example you've provided is partial and hasn't been minimized to isolate just the problem, so I'm not able to reproduce it. At a minimum, I'd need to know your base image so I can verify the `.bashrc` file is getting processed.

Comment: your answer is useful, but the main problem is I need to add environment variable od `PYTHONPATH` to docker-compose file. thanks anyway.

Comment: @RaymondCheng glad you found your solution. As mentioned above, I wanted to verify the bashrc was getting processed but needed to see what the contents were, requiring a [mcve] or at least knowing your base image.

Comment: Hi @BMitch, I've mentioned from my question the system is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @RaymondCheng that sounded like a host OS, or are you saying you have `FROM ubuntu:16.04` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi @BMich，, yes my docker Image is ubuntu 16.04, it's a little bit confusing from my question, I should say the docker system is ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Try to start docker compose with command:

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/models/research:/models/research/slim" docker-compose up -d
```