# Setting container PATH with an ENV parameter

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which includes the following:

```
 environment:
      DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/some/dir
```

I would like to add that path to my container. 
In my DockerFile I add:

```
RUN echo "export PATH=$PATH:${DOCUMENT_ROOT}" >> /root/.bashrc
```

But it doesn't work. It seems the ENV parameter isn't available.

What's the problem ?

Yaron

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Container Start Command Did Not Get .bashrc variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940777/docker-container-start-command-did-not-get-bashrc-variables)

Comment: Most typical paths to running Docker containers don't read a `.bashrc` file at all (and the popular Alpine base image doesn't even have bash).  Injecting running software into a container this way is unreliable; you'd be better off installing it directly into `/usr/bin` in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ARG some_variable_name    
RUN echo "export PATH=$PATH:${some_variable_name}" >> /root/.bashrc
```

You should use `ARG` in Dockerfile and set arguments in build command:

```
docker build --build-arg some_variable_name=a_value
```

> ARG is only available during the build of a Docker image (RUN etc),
>   not after the image is created and containers are started from it
>   (ENTRYPOINT, CMD). You can use ARG values to set ENV values to work
>   around that.

or in docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  somename:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        some_variable_name: a_value
```

[Understanding Docker Build Args, Environment Variables and Docker Compose Variables](https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the detailed info !