# How to add alias/keyword to docker in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a script that runs robot framework tests called runRobotFrameworkTests.sh  I do not want users to have to write the script name but instead write it like a normal robot command as most likely the command to e executed will come form a different application. So I want to change the meaning of robot keyword to runRobotFramewrokTests.sh

`RUN touch ~/.bash_profile`

`RUN echo "alias robot="runRobotFrameworkTests.sh"" > ~/.bash_profile`

`RUN source ~/.bash_profile`

I tried creating a bash profile and source it the issue is that when I use the image the source is not saved. So I need to source the file again when I enter the image.

Comment: use `ENV robot runRobotFrameworkTests.sh`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52940777/596285

Comment: I tried this ```ENV robot runRobotFrameworkTests.sh``` but it didn't work. It still takes the actual keyword